# Android: select a different layout based on the device selected

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-activity

Is there a way to select a different layout for an Android Activity based on the type of the device?

I try to be more clearer.
I have two layout: *home_layout_phone.xml* and *home_layout_tablet.xml*. They are equal but the objects have different proportions, and in the HomeActivity.java I want to do something like this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.home_layout_phone.xml); //if the device is a phone
setContentView(R.layout.home_layout_tablet.xml); //if the device is a tablet
```

How can I do this? I'm using AndroidStudio 1.5.1. Thanks for your answers and sorry for my bad English, I'm Italian.

Comment: check out here : http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseAliasFilters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple layout for several device configurations by using configuration qualifiers.

> Android supports several configuration qualifiers that allow you to
>   control how the system selects your alternative resources based on the
>   characteristics of the current device screen. A configuration
>   qualifier is a string that you can append to a resource directory in
>   your Android project and specifies the configuration for which the
>   resources inside are designed.

You may have something like:

- List item layout/home_layout.xml (for phones)
- List item layout-xlarge/home_layout.xml (for bigger devices)

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers

Comment: Thanks it works now. I was sure it was a simple problem to solve, but I could not find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Use one layout file name. For instance, `home_layout.xml`. This will be your phone layout. Now to create a different layout for a tablet, in Android Studio right-click the layout folder and select **New** > **Layout resource file**. Name this file the same name (`home_layout`) and under available qualifiers, select how you will determine what is a tablet. For instance, you can choose when a width exceeds 600 dp. As seen below:

[image]

When you setContentView, simply:

```
setContentView(R.layout.home_layout);
```

And the proper layout will be chosen based on the width of the device in this case.